# Bootstrap grid column padding applied differently on div tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for a simple personal site and trying to figure out why the CSS rule for padding on columns applies itself differently on different divs. Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tracyak13/hkby34L5/) for the HTML and CSS - you can see the white div beneath the about me panel is wider. They have the same column classes so I can't identify why it would affect them differently.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row name-header">
    <span class="col-xs-12">Tracy King</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
    <div class="row-panel">
      <p>About Me</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-panel col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
    <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
      doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
      veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim
      ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
      consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque
      porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
      velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore
      magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum
      exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi
      consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit
      esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo
      voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
    <div class="row-panel">
      <p>Code Samples</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
    <div class="row-panel">
      <p>Sample Apps</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
    <div class="row-panel">
      <p>Other Projects</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is some custom CSS I included in the fiddle. I thought it may be more helpful to look at it there but I can move it to my question if need be. Thanks in advance. Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: They are the same width. It's just that the white div has a background color and the about me div does not. Background color is applied to the padding. It gives the illusion that the white div is wider, but if you look at them through a browser inspector tool, you will see they are the same width.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, apply `content-panel` to each div and you'll see the `padding` you are talking about [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxtxcqas/)

Comment: I see - if I add the content-panel class on a div inside the div that calls out my columns, it's the width I was hoping for. Thanks for calling it out!

Answer (score 0):

be careful when ever  you are using **col-*** classes u are putting **row** div before them

Example

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8"></div>
   <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8"></div>
</div>
```

basically the row div has negative margin that adjust the padding of your col div.

so you have to use standard structure  bootstrap i.e

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in your case u are not using **row** div  after **name-header** class div that appearing issue with padding

Answer (score 0):

Agree with answer given by Ismail Farooq.

There is defined structure in bootstrap.
Some basic rules:

1) Add container/ container-fluid class before row class

2) Add row class before any col-* class

3) Even for nested col-* , add row before col-*